# in macOS, shell escape to bash not zsh

Tags: macos, shell

On macOS I've set my login shell to bash instead of zsh, which became the default in Catalina (Terminal > Preferences > General > Shells open with: > /bin/bash).

But when I shell escape from vi (from Terminal), the shell command is still run by zsh.
How can I make vi spawn not zsh but rather bash (or at least whatever's in Terminal > Preferences), so a shell escape can run commands defined in ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting only sets the shell used by Terminal. You need to set your log-in shell with `chsh -s /bin/bash` to make Bash the default one on any other application.

You can also try `set shell=/bin/bash` in your `.vimrc`

Comment: I'd already done chsh, apparently.  Adding that line to .vimrc changed zsh to bash, so I'm accepting this answer.
But to make vi read ~/.bashrc, it must be `set shell=/bin/bash\ -i`.  (Also `\ -l` to read ~/.bash_profile.)

Comment: `chsh` should work. I updated my answer because I forgot the `-s` flag, maybe that's why it didn't work for you